# Difference between Sencha-touch-all and Sencha-touch.js library files?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Still not clear with [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153900-Difference-between-sencha-touch.js-and-sencha-touch-all.js-library-files). I am testing with simple login form (Version is 2.2.1 and no external CSS or JS). After looking up the resource consuming, I am confused with js should i prefer either (sencha-touch.js or sencha-touch-all.js) for development and production. By default the microloader maps to sencha-touch.js. Should i change it?

sencha-touch.js -->  [image]

sencha-touch-all.js  -->  [image]

Here it just give only 29 hits to server but downloading 4 mb of file which is larger than sencha-touch

Comment: *sencha-touch.js has the bare minimum classes in it (no widgets, etc)... sencha-touch-all.js has everything in it.* already mentioned in your quoted link

Comment: Then why sencha-touch.js give 322 hits to server with basic app. This is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sencha-touch.js will be making a request to individual source files for each component your app requires in. sencha-toucha-all.js includes all components by default.

See this guide in the docs for more info:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/building

More specifically, this is what you should be doing:
- use sencha-touch.js in development
- have each of your files require in all the sencha touch components/proxies etc it needs
- when you want to go to production, use the sencha app build command in your terminal to build to a single, minified javascript file which then contains all your code and all the sencha touch code your app needs.